# Trying to install Python 3.8

Tags: apt, software-installation, snap

I am trying hard to install python 3.8, but using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice apport-symptoms distro-info-data gdisk gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 iso-codes libaccountsservice0 libappstream4 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-bin libgstreamer1.0-0 libmspack0
  libnetplan0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpython3-stdlib libstemmer0d libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-openssl libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 packagekit packagekit-tools python-apt-common python3-minimal run-one squashfs-tools
  zerofree
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu relies significantly on python and changing the python interpreter on your installed system can break the system. If you need a specific version, it's safer to do this in a VM

Comment: Stop trying so hard. Your output suggests that you already succeeded: `python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)`. That's the correct version for Ubuntu 20.04, and should have already been installed (your system *needs* it)